# add View by using WindowManager, but can back key press

Tags: android-windowmanager

I've add a View, by using WindowManager.

It shows properly what I wanted to do,

but I have a problem.
this is the problem.

- back key press doesn't affect under android component(like activity)

what I want is my added view can focusable, ( can click the view's inner button ) 
only when click the view,
and outside of the view can process their work. 
( for example, if there is a button, can be clicked, and when back key press, top activity was gone )

but if I add a flag - WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
then I can't receive onClick method on my added view's button.
but back button work correctly.

otherwise, if i remove the flag -I can receive onClick callback, 
but now back button doesn't work.

I have a dilema. :(

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have your View override

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
```

to do something when back is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Override dispatchKeyEvent of your View

```
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
{
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
{
    // handle back press
    // if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    return true;
}
return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

Add a Float window by WindowManager, for example, add a view to screen bottom:

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(); 
layoutParams.width   = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
layoutParams.height  = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
layoutParams.type= WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
layoutParams.flags   =  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
layoutParams.format  = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
layoutParams.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

FrameLayout view = new FrameLayout(getActivity()) {
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    // do you code
                    return true;
                }
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            }
        };
windowManager.addView(view, layoutParams);
```